# Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' line: 8 file: Code.gs

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I don't understand what I did wrong here
Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' line: 8 file: Code.gs
I was working on google docs script editor

I tried removing and adding the dot back but didn't work so the script is below

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  ui.alert(
    'Hello!',
    'Welcome to JNT_Network. This is a place for people to be free, if you are against us finding unblockers, we respectfully ask that you leave this doc and never come back. Thanks!',
    ui.ButtonSet.OK
  );
  .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Credits')
          .addItem('Joseph(Owner)', 'joseph2'))
      .addToUi();
}

function joseph2() {
  DocumentApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp, SlidesApp or FormApp.
      return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('j');
}
```

```
the j in the html service is j.html
```

Comment: The previous line ends with `;` so you can't use `.` at the beginning of the next line. Get rid of the `;` on line 7.

Comment: A decent IDE would catch errors like this while you're coding.

Comment: Use `ui.addSubmenu`

Comment: `ui.alert()` returns the button the user selected, not the `ui`, so you can't chain other `ui` methods on it.

Comment: That's a different logic problem, not a syntax error.

Comment: well that's the error that shows up

Comment: What error shows up? I was referring to the comment about the menu not appearing, but you deleted it.

Comment: this error started happening when I tried to do the html service so I could add another line below the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create the menu first, then call `addSubMenu()` on that.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  ui.alert(
    'Hello!',
    'Welcome to JNT_Network. This is a place for people to be free, if you are against us finding unblockers, we respectfully ask that you leave this doc and never come back. Thanks!',
    ui.ButtonSet.OK
  );
  ui.createMenu('Main Menu').addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Credits')
      .addItem('Joseph(Owner)', 'joseph2'))
    .addToUi();
}

function joseph2() {
  DocumentApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp, SlidesApp or FormApp.
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('j');
}
```

See the example in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui)